# Can't figure out how to add multiple times

Tags: python, time

How do I use a function to add a number of different times together in the format Minutes:Seconds:Tenths?
I'm trying to create a program to add different rally stage times together but I can't figure out how to do it. There can be anywhere from 4 to 14 stages in a day so I want the number of times to be able to be changed.

Here's my rather pitiful attempt at it:

```
x = int(input("How many stages are there? "))

def StageTimes(x):
        a = int(input("Stage time (Minutes): "))
        b = int(input("Stage time (Seconds): "))
        c = int(input("Stage time (Tenths): "))
        if b > 60:
            b - 60 = NewB
            a + 1 = NewA
        else:
            b = NewB
            a = NewA
        print(f"{NewA:03}",":",f"{NewB:02}",":",)

StageTimes(x)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculate the total number of seconds in a loop by multiplying minutes by 60 and dividing tenths by 10.

At the end of the loop, convert this total back to minutes and seconds, then use a single f-string to format everything as you want.

```
def StageTimes(x):
    total_time = 0
    for stage in range(1, x+1):
        minutes = int(input(f"Stage {stage} time (Minutes): "))
        seconds = int(input(f"Stage {stage} time (Seconds): "))
        tenths = int(input(f"Stage {stage} time (Tenths): "))
        total_time += minutes * 60 + seconds + tenths/10
    total_minutes = int(total_time // 60)
    total_seconds = total_time % 60
    print(f"{total_minutes:03d}:{total_seconds:04.1f}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do your own date math, it's built into Python.

Another way to have dynamic number of stages would be to have a special value (such as -1) to end the data input.

```py
from datetime import timedelta

total = timedelta()

stage = 1
while True:
    minutes = int(input(f"Stage {stage} time, Minutes (-1 to end): "))
    if minutes < 0:
        break
    seconds = int(input(f"Stage {stage} time, Seconds            : "))
    tenths  = int(input(f"Stage {stage} time, Tenths             : "))
    t = timedelta(seconds=seconds, milliseconds=tenths*100, minutes=minutes) 
    print(t, end="\n\n")
    stage += 1
    total += t

print(f"Total time: is {total}")
```

**Output**

```java
Stage 1 time, Minutes (-1 to end): 1   
Stage 1 time, Seconds            : 2
Stage 1 time, Tenths             : 3
0:01:02.300000

Stage 2 time, Minutes (-1 to end): 4
Stage 2 time, Seconds            : 5
Stage 2 time, Tenths             : 6
0:04:05.600000

Stage 3 time, Minutes (-1 to end): 7
Stage 3 time, Seconds            : 8
Stage 3 time, Tenths             : 9
0:07:08.900000

Stage 4 time, Minutes (-1 to end): -1
Total time: is 0:12:16.800000
```

**Output2**

```java
Stage 1 time, Minutes (-1 to end): 1441
Stage 1 time, Seconds            : 2
Stage 1 time, Tenths             : 3
1 day, 0:01:02.300000

Stage 2 time, Minutes (-1 to end): 2882
Stage 2 time, Seconds            : 5
Stage 2 time, Tenths             : 6
2 days, 0:02:05.600000

Stage 3 time, Minutes (-1 to end): -1
Total time: is 3 days, 0:03:07.900000
```